# Why does I am getting duplicated contacts in my web server?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask, androidhttpclient

I need your kind support....I am developing android application that stores user contacts on web server.
When I'm trying to upload contacts from my android phone to my server via php; it uploads some of my contacts properly (almost 250 contacts ) but after that It will duplicate the rest with a single contact detail(Total number of contacts in my phone are 1117)[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xUw0.jpg).This is the Android code I have used:

```
   public class AllContacts extends Activity {
        // To get the logged in user id from sqlite databse
        private SQLiteHandler db;
int  i =0;


Cursor phones, email;

ArrayList<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_list_item);



    TextView txt =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    //Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

    final String[] projection = {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
    };
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + ("1") + "'";
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    phones  =  getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1", null, sortOrder);

    txt.setText("Total: " + phones.getCount() + " contacts");

    phones.moveToFirst();
    // Iterate every contact in the phone



}



// submitContacts method is executed when a backup button is pressed
public void submitContacts(View arg0) {
    /* Start an activity for result with request code 1
    *  LoginActivity is started to check whether the user is logged in or not
    *  if the user is logged in LoginActivity will send a result code to AllContacts activity
    */
    if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        Intent intent=new Intent(AllContacts.this,LoginActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
    else{
        makeText(AllContacts.this, "You need internet access to run this application",
                LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.v("Home", "############################You are not online!!!!");

    }


}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 1
    if(requestCode==1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
            /**
             * Checks if the device has Internet connection.
             *
             * @return <code>true</code> if the phone is connected to the Internet.
             */


            if(isNetworkAvailable()){
                InsertData task1 = new InsertData();
                task1.execute(new String[]{"http://172.22.68.58:80/norton2/insert.php"});
                //Intent in = new Intent(this, AllContacts.class); // if not working use new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
                //startActivity(in);
            }

            else{
                makeText(AllContacts.this, "You need internet access to run this application",
                        LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.v("Home", "############################You are not online!!!!");

            }




        }
    }
}
private class InsertData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(AllContacts.this);
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private String result;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //  dialog.setMessage("Backing up your Data...");
        //dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {


        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
        if (phones != null && phones.moveToFirst()) {
            int total = phones.getCount();
            Log.e("Uploaded count", "" + phones.getCount());

            for (String url1 : urls) {
                for (; i < phones.getCount(); i++){
                    try {
                        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

                        String user_id = user.get("uid");
                        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId",user_id));
                        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtName", phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME))));
                        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtTel", phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))));
                        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtMajor", phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID))));

                        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url1);
                        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

                        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);



                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        makeText(AllContacts.this, e.toString(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return false;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        makeText(AllContacts.this, e.toString(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                    phones.moveToNext();
                    Log.e("Uploaded contact count", "" + i);

                    int progress = ((i+1) * 100) / total;
                    publishProgress(progress);
                    Log.v("Home", "************************Progress "+progress);
                }
            }
        }

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        TextView txt =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        txt.setText("Backup percentage: " + progress[0]+"%");
        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

    }

    protected void onPostExecute (Boolean result){

        if (result == true) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            makeText(AllContacts.this, "Backup Successful!", LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            makeText(AllContacts.this, "Error", LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

}
```

Comment: where is the duplication occuring? your android app is sending dupes, or the dupes are created on the server?

Comment: I used db.getUserDetails() purposely..the problem is on "st_name" column. it's duplicated after 250 row... have you seen the image?

Comment: Yeah u are right but the row before 250th are different...and uploaded correctly

Comment: The duplications are occuring on the server...my guess is the android app is sending the dupes..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a deep look at the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) so you can understand how onCreate() method gets called.

Comment: Can you tell me the problem you have noticed in the `code`?